# Lua C API: Push pointers as a userdata

Tags: c, api, lua

I have a pointer address which points to a userdata. I retrieved the address like so:

```
*(uint32_t*)lua_touserdata(L, -1)
```

Later on, I want to push that userdata back on top the stack by using the pointer. If this is possible, what must be done?

Comment: If you want to store a reference to a userdatum so you can push it back onto the Lua stack at a later time, I suggest using the functions `luaL_ref` and `luaL_unref`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new user data after retrieving the pointer to the one you already created via lua_newuserdata(). Then set the underlying value of the pointer to the value of the underlying value of the first userdata. It should look something like this:

```
int *ud1 = lua_touserdata( L, -1 ); // Get userdata previously created

int *ud2 = lua_newuserdata( L, sizeof( int ) ); // Create new userdata
*ud2 = *ud1; // Set value of new userdata to the value of the previous userdata

// Userdata has been successfully "pushed"
assert(
        *( (int*) lua_touserdata( L, -1 ) ) == 
        *( (int*) lua_touserdata( L, -2 ) ) 
);
```

Comment: The assert passes for me. Am I incorrect to assume that I could continue adding to the stack after "*ud2 = *ud1;"? E.g lua_getfield(-1, "field")

Comment: Yes you are correct. What was done in the example I gave will not keep you from adding to the stack.